# Can't get an entity property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

There is a problem with my Db which I figured only now, when I started to work at the web api.
 
 My **USER** entity:

```
public class User { get; set; }
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is **ACTIVITY**

```
public class Activity

{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I added an activity and checked in SSMS. Everything seems to be good, there is a field named UserId which stores the id. My problem is when I try to get a **User** from an **Activity** because I keep getting null objects. I didn't set anything special in my **DbContext** for this.

This is where I'm trying to get an User from an Activity object:

```
public ActionResult ActivityAuthor(int activityId)
{
    Activity activityItem = unitOfWork.Activity.Get(activityId);   
    return Json(unitOfWork.User.Get(activityItem.User.UserId));
}
```

Relation between User and Activity 
[image]

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't compile, you have two `UserId` properties

Comment: you need to show how you're actually using this, and where the problem occurs.

Comment: Can you show the EF Diagram, the Relational Diagram, where is the problem happening in your code.

Comment: The User property is a navigation property and should be marked as virtual.

Comment: Public class User instead of public int UserId { get; set; } on your first line for your user entity looks a bit more appropriate in the context you're working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User property of Activity class should be marked as virtual. It enables entity framework to make a proxy around the property and loads it more efficiently.

Somewhere in your code you should have a similar loading method as following :

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())

{
    var activity = context.Activities
                        .Where(a => a.ActivityId == id)
                        .FirstOrDefault<Activity>();

   context.Entry(activity).Reference(a => a.User).Load(); // loads User

}
```

This should load the User object and you won't have it null in your code.

Check this link for more information [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to add the load method in my custom context for every entity?

Comment: Try turning off lazy loading. context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false. Actually, I do not recommend this since you have to optimize your data access layer and only load what you need.

Answer (score 1):

my psychic debugging powers are telling me that you're querying the `Activity` table without `Include`-ing the User

```
using System.Data.Entity;

...

var activities = context.Activities
    .Include(x => x.User)
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, you don't need `Include` if you select properties of `User` as part of your query

```
var vms = context.Activities
    .Select(x => new ActivityVM() {UserName = x.User.Name})
    .ToList();
```